# How to use MvvmLight along with System.Windows.Interactivity?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Very simple question: **How to use MvvmLight along with System.Windows.Interactivity?!**

This is how my packages looks like:

```
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Expression.Blend.Sdk" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MvvmLightLibs" version="5.2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Can anyone suggest me, which exactly versions should I use to make this kind of code works, without errors/warnings?

```
    <userControls:MyUserControl x:Name="Foo" Margin="10,110,10,10" BorderStrokeThickness="5">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="FooClick">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=ClickCommand}" 
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </userControls:MyUserControl>
```

I get different error messages on line with `EventToCommand`. Now I have error:

> **Cannot add instance of type 'EventToCommand' to a collection of type 'TriggerActionCollection'. Only items of type 'T' are allowed.**

few seconds ago I had:

> **The type 'EventToCommand' from assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform' is built with an older version of the
>   Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 4
>   project.**

and I didn't change nothing:/ (rebuild/reopened solution few times)

EDIT: I just recompiled, I now I have second error again

EDIT2:

right now I have:

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"

xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

I cannot add (I do have GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras dll in references)

```
xmlns:command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your namespaces, they should be:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

Comment: This is crazy. I've installed MvvmLightLibs 5.2.0. But intellisense doesn't see `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command` in my xaml file. I do see references for those dlls though :/ I have `xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"` right now

Comment: Reproduce your code in my sand box project. And everything goes right: I am able to use EventToCommand without warnings and binding to command work well.
That is my actual namespaces:
`xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
 xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"`
Can you remove nuget packages (uninstall them), then remove all references from your project and then install required references again?

Comment: @lerhe61 thanks, can you check my simple code: https://github.com/robertwojnar/MvvmDemo1

It's just single view, if you could check if the error appears at your machine

Comment: Just try you code and everything is ok. Get Loaded message just after window was loaded.

Comment: it works for me too, but I have this error in the designer and can't see preview of my view :/

Comment: Hm, everything is ok on my machine. No design time errors (Windows 10 + .Net 4.5.2 installed)

Answer (score 0):

I have just stumbled across this solution (work around) which provides a way for us to continue our work with the XAML and have the preview update appropriately.

When the "Enable project code" option is enabled the exact errors appear for me.  After disabling this feature the errors no long appear and productive work can continue.

This is a thorn that has plagued me (and I am sure many others) for months.  Hopefully the underlying bug which causes this is resolved soon.  Until then I pray this answer can be as helpful to you as it was for me.

[image: Enable project code]

[image: Cannot add instance of type 'EventToCommand' to a collection of type 'TriggerActionCollection'. Only items of type 'T' are allowed.]

[image: The type 'EventToCommand' from assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project.]

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling on this page I have had exactly the same problem, everything worked in build but the designer didn't work.

I solved it by setting my target framework from 4.6 to **.net framework 4**

This is how I did it

1. remove all galasoft nugget references and remove system.windows.interactivity
2. go to project settings -> application-> target framework and set it on .net Framework 4
3. put the references back, this time they will all be using the same framework

This might result in an build error caused by system.Windows.interactivity
(file not found error)

1. open App.config
2. remove the "system.Windows.interactivity" dependentAssembly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past `Cannot add instance of type 'EventToCommand' to a collection of type 'TriggerActionCollection'. Only items of type 'T' are allowed` by doing the following:

1. Clean the solution
2. Delete `bin` and `obj` directories
3. Restart Visual Studio
4. Rebuild the solution